# Regarding generating short content from long text in strapi

Tags: wordpress, migration, content-management-system, strapi

i have a query regarding how can we generate short content from long text in strapi?(eg:-excerpt in wordpress) . I can generate the slug from he title, but not able to generate excerpt.Did anyone faced this issue?

I need to generate excerpt(short content) from the description(long text) automatically.